# ImportError: cannot import name 'DecisionBoundaryDisplay' from 'sklearn.inspection'

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I imported sklearn DecisionBoundaryDisplay via the below command in my Google Colab file.

```
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay
```

And I'm getting the following error.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'DecisionBoundaryDisplay' from 'sklearn.inspection'

I even installed the following packages & also tried by restarting my runtime but still I'm getting the error.

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn

!pip install scipy

!pip3 install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 12):

what worked for me was installing scikit learn 1.1.0, i had version 1.0.2 before and got the same error you're encountering.

pip install -U scikit-learn --user

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not work in colab.

Answer (score 6):

It seems [DecisionBoundaryDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html) is a new feature and it  is currently in an unstable development version. To use it, you need [to install the nightly build](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-nightly-builds).

Comment: It does not work in colab.